# SQLite detection error while deploying my code in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have done changes in gem file, db.yml to deploy my code in heroku as:

Gem file:

```
group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a 
debugger 
 console
gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
# Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
 gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
 gem 'factory_bot_rails'
 gem 'selenium-webdriver'
 gem 'bullet'
gem 'web-console'
gem 'faker'
end

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

db.yml

```
 production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
 database: production
```

I have done these changes but still it's showing error as " Failed to install gems via Bundler.Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku". Is there anything i have to change for deploying my code in heroku??

Comment: Can you share your Heroku deployment code? You need to update your deployment code to bundle without development group ..

Answer (score 1):

Based on: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration#environment-variable-behavior documentation

You can exclude development group in your bundler config as follows:

```
$ heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT=development:test:ci
```

which will fix your problem, as it won't bundle `sqlite3` gem.

**Note**: I highly recommend using PostgreSQL during development. Maintaining parity between your development and deployment environments prevents subtle bugs from being introduced because of differences between your environments.

Comment: Could you share full `db.yml` and `Gemfile` ? also could you indent it correctly and without syntax errors. The ones that you shared looks incomplete and unintended correctly.